# merge two rows if first column is same in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have the following data

```
11111 | aff | baucj | blah | blah
13331 | azvaff | bcacj | blah | blah
11111 | aasfff | aascj | blah | blah
13331 | aafzvff | baucj | blah | blah
12221 | arthrf | bacsfucj | blah | blah
12221 | ddhrhsd | hdafasfacj | blah | blah
```

I want these to be merged like

```
11111 | aff | baucj | blah | blah | 11111 | aasfff | aascj | blah | blah
13331 | azvaff | bcacj | blah | blah | 13331 | aafzvff | baucj | blah | blah
12221 | arthrf | bacsfucj | blah | blah | 12221 | ddhrhsd | hdafasfacj | blah | blah
```

Comment: Can you format your data please? (use the code tags in the editor)

Comment: it's done now..

Comment: please ignore the <br /> it's not present in actual file and i don't want it.

Comment: can you please explain what on earth you are talking about? you want to merge these in what exactly? is this a programming question? cause notepad++ is a programming software. if so what language are you trying to do this in. and IF this is a programming question, you need to ask this in stack overflow